# Resolving circular references in probability-graph

Tags: graph-theory

*(Apologies, if the title is not accurate/useful, I'm not sure what else to call it... Ideas welcome...)*

Let's say I have a game that consists of several states ***S<sub>1</sub>***, ***S<sub>2</sub>***, ***S<sub>3</sub>***, ... and coin-tosses that transition you from one state to some other state. There also is a state ***W*** where you win and a state ***L*** where you loose. Games always start in state ***S<sub>1</sub>***. What is the probability **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>1</sub>***) of winning such a game.

As an example, let's take the following rules to the game:

- ***S<sub>1</sub>***: Heads brings you to ***S<sub>2</sub>***, tails brings you to ***S<sub>3</sub>***
- ***S<sub>2</sub>***: Heads brings you to ***S<sub>3</sub>***, tails brings you to ***L***
- ***S<sub>3</sub>***: Heads brings you to ***L***, tails brings you to ***W***

Now, if I need to figure out what the overall chance of winning the game is (given fair coin-tosses), I can simply start at the bottom:

- **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>3</sub>***) = 0.5 * 0% + 0.5 * 100% = 50%
- **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>2</sub>***) = 0.5 * **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>3</sub>***) + 0.5 * 0% = 25%
- **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>1</sub>***) = 0.5 * **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>2</sub>***) + 0.5 * **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>3</sub>***) = 37.5%

The problem comes in when I, for example, replace the last rule with this:

- ***S<sub>3</sub>***: Heads brings you back to ***S<sub>1</sub>***, tails brings you to ***W***

Notice, how this creates a circular reference where **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>3</sub>***) depends on **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>1</sub>***) and vice versa.

I need an algorithm that a computer can perform automatically to solve for **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>1</sub>***) for **any** possible rule-set for an arbitrary number of states and for "coins" that have more than 2 sides (i.e. each state transitions to a random choice among several possible following states including immediate loop-back). I might even be faced with a situation where the "coins" aren't fair, i.e. the probabilities to transition to the next states are not all equal.

I think I remember something that this can be solved with a matrix equation, but I'm not even sure what to call this problem to do a real Google search for an answer... I don't even know what tags to pick. :)

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Given all values are probabilities that sum to 1, I *have a feeling* that this problem should always have one unique solution. Is that correct?

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain), in which case you're looking for the probability of winning in [the steady-state distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Steady-state_analysis_and_limiting_distributions).

Comment: @phs Awesome! Yes! I think that's it. Now I can go search, too! Thanks. And, I even remember vaguely that a long time back I did this in college... :)

Comment: Groovy.  Will the answer below float the boat?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain), in which case you're looking for the probability of winning in [the steady-state distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Steady-state_analysis_and_limiting_distributions).

As Wikipedia explains, a (discrete) Markov chain is a directed state graph equipped with a probability distribution on the out-edges of each vertex.  We can use these models to understand flow on the graph in a probabilistic way.  One way to visualize this is to imagine one or more random "walkers" moving on the graph according to the distributions.

A critical ingredient of the guarantees we are about to examine is the [Markov property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property), which essentially says that a random walker has no memory.  Instead their behavior is determined entirely by the (fixed) transition distribution of the state node they're standing on.

One could imagine an initial distribution of a great many random walkers on a graph, who are allowed to walk for an unbounded amount of time.  When the graph is [suitable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Ergodicity), the Markov property guarantees that the distribution of walkers "levels out" and converges on a single steady-state distribution, regardless of the initial distribution.  By calculating this steady-state distribution, one can ask questions of it such as "What is the probability of a random walker being in state `X`?"

Your problem appears to fit the requirements of a Markov model (particularly, the absorbing variant as you noticed.)  In that formulation "winning" becomes arrival at a certain set of states.  You can therefore calculate the odds of winning by first calculating the steady-state distribution and then asking it the probability of being in the winning states.